# Image charge method to find electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

The following is a question from my tutorial on boundary value problems and image charge method-

A point charge +q is placed at (0, 0, d) above a grounded infinite conducting plane defined by z = 0. There are no charges present anywhere else.  What is the magnitude of electric field at        (0, 0,-d)?

The provided answer is '0'.

But I don't know how?

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the image method can be used to calculate the potential (and hence the electric field) in the region $z>0$, with a negative charge $-q$ located at $(0,0,-d)$, since the potential would be $V(x,y,0)=0$, in this case. But for points in the region $z<0$, the potential is given by the solution of Lapalace equation $\nabla^2 V=0$, with boundary condition $V(x,y,0)=0$. It is easy to see that the trivial solution $V(x,y,z)=0$ satisfies these conditions. But since the solution is unique, we conclude that the potential is identicaly null in this region, and so is the electric field.

Comment: In other words, the conducting plane at z=0 is an infinite Faraday cage for the region z<0 such that this region does not see the charge at z=d and therefore has the potential of its boundary, i.e. null everywhere.